# How to refresh page while dragging component from side panel in AEM6.1?

Tags: aem

My need is to refresh the page when author drags component from side panel onto parsys. The component displays the edit tool bar only after page refresh. This is problem only in touch ui since classic editConfig displays edit bar always on the page. How do I sneak a page refresh action when author drags component from side panel?

Comment: not sure if I understood you correctly. are you looking to refresh the page 'while' dragging or after 'dragging and dropping'. if its the later did you try adding `afterinsert="REFRESH_PAGE"` to your editConfig?

Comment: cq:editConfigs are ingeneral not working in touch ui. Am not sure if this is expected.

Comment: yes. _The configuration is common to both the touch-optimized and classic UI, albeit with certain, specific differences_. See - https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components/components-basics.html#Edit%20Behavior

Comment: nopes. didnt work and I figured out a workaround. Please tell me if cq:editconfiglisteners works for you in touch ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation here is what I found and it works.

- cq:editConfigs and cq:EditListenersConfig are not working for touch ui. Even after adding afterInsert="REFRESH_PAGE", the page refresh doesn't happen.
- The java script that is executed when drag&drop action happens in touch ui is:

  ```
  /libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/clientlibs/editor/js/edit/edit.actions.js
  ```
- So I created an overlay, basically copied the js into my application client libraries and added below condition in  self.doInsert() function:

  ```
    self.doInsert = function (component, insertBehavior, editableNeighbor, historyConfig, additionalData) {
   if(component.componentConfig.path == '/apps/sample/components/media/rich-media' || component.componentConfig.path == '/apps/sample/components/media/tiled-display')
      { window.location.reload(); }
  ```
- Now page is refreshing after author drags the component.

Please let me know if this is advisable way and why cq:EditListenersConfig is not working in touch ui.

Comment: This is a hacky way to refresh the parsys/page. You have to keep add if conditions for all your components. There should be another work around for this.